# RegQueryValueEx not working with a Release version but working fine with Debug

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, registry

I'm trying to read some ODBC details from a registry and for that I use RegQueryValueEx. The problem is when I compile the release version it simply cannot read any registry values.

The code is:

```
CString odbcFuns::getOpenedKeyRegValue(HKEY hKey, CString valName)
{
    CString retStr;
    char *strTmp = (char*)malloc(MAX_DSN_STR_LENGTH * sizeof(char));
    memset(strTmp, 0, MAX_DSN_STR_LENGTH);
    DWORD cbData;
    long rret = RegQueryValueEx(hKey, valName, NULL, NULL, (LPBYTE)strTmp, &cbData);
    if (rret != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        free(strTmp);
        return CString("?");
    }
    strTmp[cbData] = '\0';
    retStr.Format(_T("%s"), strTmp);
    free(strTmp);
    return retStr;
}
```

I've found a workaround for this - I disabled Optimization (/Od), but it seems strange that I needed to do that. Is there some other way? I use Visual Studio 2005. Maybe it's a bug in VS?

Almost forgot - the error code is 2 (as the key wouldn't be found).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize `cbData` - set it to be `MAX_DSN_STR_LENGTH - 1` before calling `RegQueryValueEx()`.

The problem is likely configuration-dependent because the variable is initialized  by the compiler in one configuration and left uninitialized in another.

Also you'll be much better of using `std::vector` for the buffer - less code, better exception safety, less error-prone.

Comment: Yes.  In the Debug build the value will be initialized to 0xcccccccc.  Don't subtract 1.  Use the CRegKey class to avoid these traps.

Comment: @Hans Passant He has buffer for N characters, filles with zeroes. If he doesn't subtract 1 and the function fills all N characters the string is no longer null-terminated.

Comment: Check the SDK docs: *If the data has the REG_SZ, REG_MULTI_SZ or REG_EXPAND_SZ type, this size includes any terminating null character or characters unless the data was stored without them*

Comment: @Hans Passant: Yes, then "see remarks" follows and the remarks section says that the string might have been stored without the terminating null, so the program must be prepared to this.

Comment: Thanks, sharptooth. I guess I've missed that while preparing the code and forgot afterwards :-).
@Hans Thanks, I'll try that too.